# Can nose test's coverage report only show files that don't have 100% coverage?

Tags: code-coverage, nose

Nose has a very thorough report for the coverage in the files that you run it for. Here's an example report.

[image]

This report is usually extremely long since I have lots of files that I need to run coverage for.

How can I generate a report for only the files that have less than 100% coverage?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The report you see is produced by coverage.py, the software nose uses for coverage measurement. Coverage.py doesn't yet have a feature to omit 100% files.  So there isn't a way to generate a report like you want.

Comment: I'm not critiquing, and I am not requesting clarification. I am answering the question: the software in question doesn't have that feature.  I'll clarify my answer.